# How to get value from serialized output

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

How to get concrete value from following string stored in mysql?

{"3":"123456789","4":"ABCDEF"}

I am trying to extract these values and store them separately to other columns like COLUMN_A with value 123456789, COLUMN_B with...

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_decode` function.

```
print_r(json_decode('{"3":"123456789","4":"ABCDEF"}'));
```